# Complementary topological properties

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**‎Definition ‎1**. A topological property ‎‎$‎P‎$‎ is expansive(contractive) if for any topology ‎$  ‎\tau‎$‎ with property ‎‎$‎P‎$‎ any finer (coarser) topology ‎$ ‎\tau‎^{*}‎‎ $‎ also has property ‎‎‎$ P $‎‎.
‎

**Definition ‎2‎.** If ‎‎$‎P$‎ is an expansive topological property and ‎‎$‎Q‎$‎ is a contractive topological property then ‎‎$‎P$‎ and ‎‎$‎Q‎$‎ are called **complementary** if a topology is minimal ‎‎$‎P$‎ if and only if it is maximal ‎‎$‎Q‎$‎.‎‎

‎
**Definition ‎3‎.** A topological space is called $KC$ space if every compact subset is closed.

**Theorem:** X‎ ‎is ‎‎maximal ‎compact ‎‎‎‎$ ‎\Longleftrightarrow‎ $‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎X‎ ‎is ‎‎KC‎‎-‎minimal.

Therefore, $KC$ and compactness  are complementary.

> 1: What property can be placed instead of compactness or $KC$ to complement?
>
> 2: Do you give me some examples of topological properties  to complement each other?

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be an expansive property and let $Q$ be a contractive property. There are different types of complementarity relating the following induced poperties: (1) minimal $P$, (2) maximal $Q$, (3) $P$ and $Q$.

The definition of complementary properties you mention (iirc defined by Larson) demands the equivalence of minimal $P$ and maximal $Q$, i.e. (1)
 $\iff$ (2). Of course a topology that satifies the equivalent properties is also both $P$ and $Q$, but I do not see a reason for the converse. So there may be complementary properties $P$ and $Q$ such that being simultaneously $P$ and $Q$ does not imply being minimal $P$ (and maximal $Q$).

It seems that often you start with properties $P$ and $Q$ such that being simultaneously $P$ and $Q$ implies both minimal $P$ and maximal $Q$, i.e. (3) $\implies$ (1) and (2). Equivalently, there is no $P$ topology strictly coarser than a $Q$ topology. Let us call such properties *opposing*. It may additionaly happen that minimal $P$ already implies $Q$ (i.e. (2) $\implies$ (3)) and/or that maximal $Q$ already implies $P$ (i.e. (1) $\implies$ (3)). In the best case, all conditions (1), (2), (3) are equivalent, and in particular the properties $P$ and $Q$ are complementary.

Some examples of opposing properties:

- $T_2$ and compact – the most classical example. But neither of the extra conditions is true. There is even a maximal compact topology strictly coarser than minimal Hausdorff topology.

  $KC$ and compact – this fixes the previous situation. Showing that maximal compact is $KC$ is easy. Showing that minimal $KC$ is compact is much harder, and it is quite recent result.

  door and connected. A topological space is *door* if every its subset is open or closed. These spaces are fully classified. Moreover, every minimal door space is connected. On the other hand, not every maximal connected space is door.

  door and hyperconnected. A topology is *hyperconnected* if every two nonempty open sets meet, i.e. the topology (without the empty set) is a base of a filter. Door hyperconnected topologies are just ultrafilters, so we have the equivalence with maximal hyperconnected spaces. But not every minimal door space is hyperconnected. Also the excluded point topologies are minimal door.

  $T_1$ and having only finite proper closed sets. This one is easy since on every set there is the coarsest $T_1$ topology – consisting of all cofinite sets (and the empty set). We have all equivalences here.

  $T_D$ and nested. $T_D$ is a separation axiom between $T_0$ and $T_1$ defined by the condition that every singleton is open in its closure. A topological space is *nested* if every two open sets are comparable by inclusion. It is equivalent to being hereditarily connected. Here we have the equivalence of all three conditions (1), (2), (3). And spaces satisfying these are Alexandrov discrete with the specialization preorder being a linear order.

  $T_0$ and strongly loosely nested. We have all equivalences here. *Strongly loosely nested* is a strengthening of nested.

Comment: I would like to use H-closed or star compact spaces to get their complementary. I know minimal Hausdorff is H-closed and the compact is H- closed, but the inverse does not exist.
  I tried very hard to figure out Under what spaces can complementary of H-closed or star compact be found?. But I did not succeed or  I wanted to see what spaces We must add  to H-closed or star compact be complemented.

Comment: @adin You should probably ask this as a separate question. And now I see you already did: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3270423/complementary-properties .